# Хеш, определение алгоритма хеширования

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, хеширование

> 15b44600cb0f32739a1fe0b769a59d9e9642e287

Хеш состоит из 40-ка символов, и как определить алгоритм его шифрования?
И возможно ли вообще узнать его исходное значение?

Comment: нет. обычно это необратимый процесс. но если есть мощный стек компов, то в принципе тратя от дня до месяца можно думаю подобрать :)

Comment: Только вот, будут ли подобранные байты *равны* тем, от которых получен хэш ?

Comment: Логично :)

Answer (score 3):

> как определить алгоритм его шифрования

1. Не алгоритм шифрования, а алгоритм хеширования, - это разные вещи;
2. если вы уверены, что эти данные, - это результат работы функции хеширования, то можно поискать все известные и посмотреть, к которой на выходе получается такое же количество байт; если это сообщение, это конкатенация 2х/3х и т.д., то вы никак не сможете определить алгоритм хеширования;
3. исходное значение узнать можно только прямым перебором всех возможных комбинаций.

Суть хеш функции в том, чтоб получить значение функции `y = f(x)` такое, чтоб, имея `"y"`, нельзя было узнать `"х"`. Поэтому сама по себе задача нахождения `"x"` по `"y"` достаточно сложна, ведь, как уже заметили коллеги, нет гарантии, что на выходе функции не будет одинаковое значение для двух разных `"x"`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно и еще как можно. Все зависит от множества факторов, если хэш составлен без [соления](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) и без повторного применения хэширования (то есть хэш от хэша) и алгоритм более-менее известный типа SHA-1 или MD5, то вполне реально за пару дней его расколотить. Загляните на форум [античат](http://forum.antichat.ru/forum76.html) - там даже устраиваются конкурсы на вскрывание хэшей.

Comment: По сути Вы говорите о подборе пароля. А ведь хэш часто используют с целью ускорения поиска данных. В этом контексте, подбор ("раскалывание") смысла не имеет.

Comment: получается, что сам алгоритм хеширования - не секретный, для конкретного случая, т.е. если это функция хеширования jvm - то, наверно, там один алгоритм, причем известный, отсюда - разобраться в этом можно, но вряд ли можно воспроизвести его опять...

Comment: да суть как раз в том чтобы алгоритм хеширования не секретный, его знают все, более того зачастую именно его открытость позволяет общественности подвергать его многочисленным проверкам на прочность. что в свою очередь сказывается на его безопасности. т.к. специалисты имеют возможность анализировать алгоритм и указывать на слабые места

Comment: Смысл хэша состоит в его неоднозначной обратимости. Это как если есть число 4, то определить в результате каких операций он получен очень сложно или 2+2 или 6-2 или 2*2. Если известен алгоритм то восстановить уже проще, но все равно сложно и неоднозначно. Обращение хэша приведет к некоему множеству значений. Допустим как в случае с числом 4 - допустим алгоритм известен: получен сложением 2-х однозначных чисел. Тогда множество бесконечных значений сведется к 3-м вариантам: 0+4, 1+3 и 2+2

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте утилиту [Hash Identifier](https://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/). Для меня определил в 100% случаев.